# HttpWebRequest: how get the session id

Tags: c#, .net, service

we are using a web service for a web site to communicate with an external server.
External server ask for a session id.

Our following code ask external server:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(ExtUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ExtAccountToUse, ExtPassword);
HttpWebResponse webResponse;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
 writer.Write(xmlOutput);
writer.Close();               
webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Is it possible to get a session id to send to external server ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: You appear to be sending XML (xmlOutput) but you set the content type as if it were a standard HTML form post, thats a little strange, why are you not used "text/xml" as the content type?

Comment: In what way does the External server "ask for a session id".

Comment: Does the external server ask for a session id on the first request you send to the server? Because it should be the responsibility of the target server to generate a valid session id that you can then reuse in the client.

Comment: In fact, external server need this id in xmlOutput data, as an xml element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the type of server you are sending the request to. For example, if you have an IIS hosted site, it expects a session id [inside a cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178582.aspx) named `ASP.NET_SessionId` (or on the request string). If you have a Java servlet engine on the other side, it expects a cookie called `JSESSIONID` (or a request path parameter `jsessionid`).

So it depends. However, setting cookies inside a HttpWebRequest is not difficult. You can use the property [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx):

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
cookies.Add(new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", sessionId));
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

The session identifier you store inside the cookie should have a particular format and again, this depends on the server type at the other end. In ASP.NET by default the class [`SessionIDManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx) is used to produce and validate session ids. This class is hard to reuse because it requires an `HttpContext`. However, you could check with Reflector how it generates a session id.

Comment: Error on cookie.domain. It can't be empty

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the external server requires an existing session ID that identifies a session created by prior requests sent to it then you need to maintain an instance of a CookieContainer for all of the requests involved.

```
 CookieContainer myExternalServerCookies = new CookieContainer();
```

With every HttpWebRequest you use to talk to the external server include this line:-

```
 request.CookieContainer = myExternalServerCookies;
```

Now when the external server sets a session cookie, it will see that cookie in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

as far as getting session ID is concerned you can get it using:

```
Session.SessionID
```

but I don't think session id on your server is of any interest to external server.

Comment: I doubt using the current servers session ID is useful in talking to an external server.